# How to use REGEXP in sqlQuery function in R

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, r

**EDIT-1**

My actual database is in MSAccess format and I am importing the data using `sqlQuery` function in `RODBC` package of R. The following is fake database I am creating so that I can provide a reproducible example using `RSQLite` package. I want to use regexp with the 
`sqlQuery` function.

End of **EDIT-1**

The following is a mock database and associated queries using `RSQLite` package. The `REGEX` (or `REGEXP`) function does not work and I could not figure out why.

```
data0 <- read.csv(textConnection(
'ID  value
P9W38   97
P9W39   17
P9W40   78
P9W41   7
P9W42_1 38
P9W42   13
P9W43   18
P9W44   76
P9W45   65
P9W46   24
P9W46_1 44
P9W47   8
P9W48   31
P9W49   82
P9W50   52
P9W50_2 55
P9W51   26
P9W52   33
P9W52_2 79
P9W53   67
P9W54   74
P9W55   55'
),sep='')

dbWriteTable(con, "Mydata", data0)
```

**These worked**

```
dbGetQuery(con, paste0(' select * from Mydata where [ID] like \'P9W38\' '))
dbGetQuery(con, paste0(' select * from Mydata where [ID] like \'P9W42%\' '))
```

**But these do not work**

```
dbGetQuery(con, paste0(' select * from Mydata where [ID] REGEX \'P9W(38|40|50)\' '))
dbGetQuery(con, paste0(' select * from Mydata where [ID] REGEX \'P9W(38|40|50)(_1){,1}\' '))
```

*Any suggestion?*

Comment: Since `like` statement worked I expected same for `regex`. Sorry I am new to SQL and I would appreciate your input in a more detail. I do not understand how I do the filtering you mentioned except in a query statement

Comment: @agstudy MySQL has a [specific extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) to normal SQL that allows for regular expressions. So you would expect this kind of thing to work.

Comment: @Stat-R Have you tried the query directly against your MySQL database, through another client? If that doesn't work, maybe it would be best to add a `mysql` tag to this question.

Comment: @Stat-R Also, have you tried that the examples given on the link above work? Like: `SELECT 'a' REGEXP '^[a-d]';` should return `1`.

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but it's been my experience that ODBC connections tend to support only the "bare minimum" features of a particular db engine. Or at least, they do not always support every feature implemented in the db itself.

Comment: Also, from the SQLite docs: "The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If a application-defined SQL function named "regexp" is added at run-time, that function will be called in order to implement the REGEXP operator."

Comment: So, may be I will just use the LIKE function repeatedly and achieve what I want. `REGEXP` would have been better though if there were more patterns to matech

Comment: Well, I agree with agstudy in that it's probably better to just do the regex in R.

Comment: Okay. My only concern was that I would be importing much more than the required number of rows before I filter them in R

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly a downside. Maybe you will have more luck (in RSQLite at least) using `GLOB` rather than `LIKE`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is inside the query you have REGEX instead of REGEXP:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

so your code should be like:

```
dbGetQuery(con, paste0(' select * from Mydata where [ID] REGEXP \'P9W(38|40|50)\' '))
dbGetQuery(con, paste0(' select * from Mydata where [ID] REGEXP \'P9W(38|40|50)(_1){,1}\' '))
```

give some feedback please, I don't work much with databases, but I think that will solve your problem

Comment: Friend! I already tried both (See my question...`REGEX` (or `REGEXP`))...No success